# vertically aligning text in a div both single line AND multi-line

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align text both when the text fits in one line AND when the text fits in two lines. There's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgD4W/)** here.

[image]

Suppose my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="Container">
   <div class="SomeClass">test text</div>
   <div class="SomeClass">some very very long text</div>  // this text is cut
</div>​
```

And that my CSS looks like this:

```
.Container{
    padding:3px 0px 6px 0px;
    height:30px;
    margin:30px 30px;}

.SomeClass{
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:28px;}​
```

At the moment, I'm using the `line-height` property: I set it to the height of the container, and that vertically aligns the text. The problem is that when the text fits in 2 lines, this doesn't work anymore. Note that the `.Container` items must be of a certain height/width AND be left with `overflow:hidden;`

Let me know if you have some suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use JS/JQuery and can you change the HTML markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I didn't understood this

> Note that the .Container items must be of a certain height AND be left
>   with overflow:hidden;

If you are giving a fixed height than I am sure it *won't fit 2 lines* in there...

And about the answer, you can use `display: table-cell`, use `vertical-align: middle;` and remove `float: left;` from `.SomeClass`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NgD4W/1/)

CSS (Ofcourse you can play with heights)

```
.Container{
    padding: 3px 0px 6px 0px;
    margin:30px 30px;
    height: 200px;
}

.SomeClass{
    width:100px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the text will fit in the given height because it's never longer than the example I provided.

Comment: @frenchie still if you need the `overflow: hidden;` than here you go http://jsfiddle.net/NgD4W/2/

Comment: well as you can see, the long text is cut because the second line overflows out of the container.

Comment: @frenchie yup I got that :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to vertically align multiple line text without using CSS3 or tables.

Line-height defines the height of the text and is a great way to vertically align single line text. Multiple line text can also be aligned using line-height but this time, you have to be wary to do proper margin calculation as the line-height is double for 2 lines, and triple for 3 lines, etc.

I suggest either using CSS3 or using php or other server side language to force line breaks '
' and then using appropriate css to offset the text vertically.

Comment: Consider using css to truncate text that is too long. This may look more pleasant to the eye and suit your needs. This requires text-overflow: ellipse; overflow: hidden; width: 100px; line-height: 18px; height: 18px;